# I am using google chart api for drawing ColumnChart in 3d But I want to draw chart like excel 3d- column chart (please see Image or code)

Tags: google-visualization

I am referring [this article](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart_old).

Please suggest what can I do?

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]}); 

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Week Ending');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Total');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Passed');  
      data.addColumn('number', 'Failed');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Incomplete');
  var options = {
    series: {
      0: { color: '#253646' },
      1: { color: '#009bde' },
      2: { color: '#8dc8ea' },
      3: { color: '#a7bbc4' }
    },
    vAxis: { viewWindow: {max: 100,min:0 }, gridlines: { color: '#f3f3f3', count: 7}},
    chartArea: {left:"5%", width:"90%"},
    vAxis :{ textStyle: {fontName: 'Aileron-Light',fontSize: 12 }},
    hAxis :{ textStyle: {fontName: 'Aileron-Light',fontSize: 12 }},
    tooltip: {textStyle:  {fontName: 'Aileron-Light',fontSize: 12}},
    legend: {textStyle:  {fontName: 'Aileron-Light',fontSize: 12,bold: false}, position: 'top', alignment: 'end' },
    pointSize: 5,
    is3D:true
  };
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart-div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
```

[image: Data Presentation]

Answer (score 0):

The 3D option in Google Charts is more or less just visual styling.  The chart you're asking for is fundamentally different.  As far as I am aware, there is no way to do this with Google Charts API.

There are other options available, but I could not find a free one for you.  The first one I did find is [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/3d-charts).  If you follow the link you'll see that they do have options to make something very similar to what you are asking for. If any of the other major chart widget vendors have a chart that can do what you are asking for, it was not clearly documented on their websites.